# Err: constructor intent undefined

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, undefined

I got this error message: Syntax error on token

This is the code I have:

```
    package com.BartH.klok;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;


public class help extends Activity {


    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }



    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonback);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, Fullscreen.class);
                startActivity(intent5);
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Basically I just want to go back to the activity 'fullscreen' after the press of 'buttonback'. But the buttons are new from me so im not sure how to do this.
This is the only error i get.

thanks for looking

Comment: *Where* did you get that exception?

Comment: Compiler error or runtime error?  If compile time, what line?

Comment: I got the error just in the editor itself

Comment: what line is the error on?  Surely the editor tells you.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I should have been more specific. It was line 40 where Sam replaced it with his code, im trying it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the current object, in this case the OnClickListener, not your Activity. Use:

```
Intent intent5 = new Intent(help.this, Fullscreen.class);
```

Also please read about [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) which state that Classes should start with an uppercase letter (CamelCase). So your Activity should be named `Help`.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, please click the check mark in this answer to accept it as the solution.

Comment: I just did, I hope it's not too late yet.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
 Intent intent5 = new Intent(help.this, Fullscreen.class);
```